# API Design - Endpoint to retrieve ressources Column names

Tags: php, laravel, api, vue.js, architecture

I would like to know what would be the best practice to get the column names of a resource.

I'm using Vue JS for the front end, and Laravel for the API and want to create a search system with a dropdown input listing all the fields of my resource, so I can make a search filtered by fields:

[image]

So my search bar is a Vue Component, and when the component is ready, I'm trying to populate the dropdown with the list of Columns.

In term of API design, what would be the better solution to implement that ?

I was thinking about 2 different endpoints, but I don't have enough experience in building API to know which one is better :

1. `api/resource_name/columns`
2. `api/metadata/resource_name/columns`

So in `solution 1`, an action in the resource controller will return the list of columns, and in the `solution 2`, a separate controller (`metadata`), will be in charge of that, and could be used for others tasks like this one.

What do you think?

Comment: REST-like API is not a database abstraction

Comment: Have you thought about creating a controller which will always accept an input dropdown regardless of a search e.g. `All Fields` and then processes the search. This way, the need to separate logic is reduced.

Comment: @tereško, what would be the way for my Front End to get this informations ?Kelvin, My problem is more about how my front end could get the list of columns, not a back end problem.

Comment: @RomainV If using laravel blade templating, this can be passed through as an array

Comment: @thisiskelvin I'm using Vue JS as a front end, and laravel for the back. So my search bar is Vue Component, and I'm trying to populate my dropdown, when the component is ready, with a HTTP request. ( I'm gonna edit my question by adding this context )

Comment: You will need to run an ajax call, using `axios`, which will make an api call to only retrieve the field names. Do you want an example?

Comment: Thanks Kelvin :) So my question is about this api call. What would the best practice ? Option 1 or Option 2 ? Using the same controller as the Ressource, and create an Action getColumn for exemple, or create another controller Metadata, which will be responsible for handling this kind of request ? It's just a matter of what is the best design for the API :)

Comment: It probably should be `GET /api/search/categories`, because of the nature of search itself.

Comment: @RomainV Personally, I would go with option 2. The `index()` method of that controller could be used to get all fields (also allowing for filtering of these fields using scopes etc). Any other specific searching e.g. category, can be done using a `CategoryController`. It will be clearer when you look back at the api in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys !